If a space deformation retracts onto a point then every neighbourhood of the point contains a path-connected neighbourhood of it
Let X be a space and $x_0$ a point in it with $r : X \rightarrow \{x_0\}$ a deformation retract.
Then we have a homotopy $H : id_X \Rightarrow \iota\circ r$, for $\iota : \{x_0\} \hookrightarrow X$ the inclusion.

Let $x$ in $X$. Then $H(x,-) : I \rightarrow X$ is a path between $x$ and $x_0$.
The same can be done with any other point $y$ in $X$, and by concatenating the two paths you get that $H(y,-)^{-1}\cdot H(x,-) : I \rightarrow X$ is a path between $x$ and $y$.

Where do I use the "for every neighbourhood there exists a path-connected neighbourhood" part?
It seems I just proved that if $X$ deformation retracts to a point then $X$ is path-connected.
Thanks in advance!

Yea, this is even true in more generality: if $X$ deformation retracts to $Y$, then one is path-connected if and only if the other is.

Why do you think you had to use this extra assumption to prove path-connectivity?

@MoisheKohan it was stated like this in a midterm exam. It seems to me they confused path-connected with nullhomotopic, as in the fifth exercise of the zeroth chapter of Hatcher's book. I was so confused in the exam. Thanks.

You should discuss this with your instructor, maybe the problem was misstated (such things do happen).

@MoisheKohan will do!

Also, good job spotting this.

Let $U$ be an open neigborhood of $x_0$ in $X$. Then $H^{-1}(U)$ is an open neigborhood of $\{x_0\} \times I$ in $X \times I$. By the tube lemma there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ in $X$ such that $V \times I \subset H^{-1}(U)$.
We have $V = H(V \times \{0\}) \subset H(V \times I) \subset U$, thus $W = H(V \times I)$ is a (not necessarily open) neighborhood of $x_0$ in $X$ which is contaioned in $U$.
Let $x \in W$. Write $x = H(v,s)$ with $(v,s) \in V \times I$ and define
$$u : I \to W, u(t) = H(v,ts) .$$
Then $u(0) = x_0$ and $u(1) = x$ which shows that $W$ is path-connected.

It should be mentioned that path connected doesn't imply locally path connected, which is what I mistakingly assumed above.
